# Is there an equivalent of "gettimeofday" in .NET

Tags: c#

I am working with .NET but I need to communicate with a logging service, unix based, that expects seconds and microseconds since the Unix epoch time.  The seconds is easily retrievable doing something like:

```
DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
TimeSpan time = DateTime.UtcNow() - UnixEpoch
int seconds = (int) time.TotalSeconds
```

however, I am unsure how to calculate the microseconds.  I could use the TotalMilliseconds property and convert it to microseconds but I believe that defeats the purpose of using microseconds as a precise measurement.  I have looked into using the StopWatch class but it doesn't seem like I can seed it with a time (Unix Epoch for example).

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks.aspx) property to get the most fine-grained level of detail. A tick is 100ns, so divide by 10 to get to microseconds.

However, that talks about the *representation precision* - it doesn't talk about the *accuracy* at all. Given the coarse granularity of `DateTime.UtcNow` I wouldn't expect it to be particularly useful. See Eric Lippert's [blog post about the difference between precision and accuracy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx) for more information.

You may want to start a stopwatch at a known time, and basically add *its* time to the "start point". Note that "ticks" from `Stopwatch` doesn't mean the same as `TimeSpan.Ticks`.

Comment: This was going to be my answer, but I didn't know the resolution of a Tick. Do this. Except, since 100ns = .1us, shouldn't you divide ticks by 10 to get microseconds?

Comment: This is the best answer, because it gives the most precision available from `UtcNow()`, but I think the `Ticks` property really isn't all that precise.

Comment: @Keith: Whoops, yes, fixing :)

Comment: +1 for pointing out [precision vs. accuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) -- it's easy to confuse the two or assume that a high precision implies an appropriate accuracy (although the article above is not really targeted at *representation precision*)

Comment: @pst: It's really easy to confuse the *three*: absolute accuracy (i.e. agreement with the atomic clock which maintains the time standard), relative accuracy aka measurement precision (under discussion here), vs representational precision aka significant digits (which Eric calls just *precision*).  In the scientific world, when the word *precision* is used alone, it most often means *measurement precision*, which is closely related to *repeatability*, and is opposite from the sense in which Eric used the term.  (similarly in the scientific world, *accuracy* deals with *bias*).

Comment: @Ben: I'm glad I entirely coincidentally used the term "representational precision" here in that case, as it's reasonably unambiguous :)

Answer (score 5):

From [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/):

```
epoch = (DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
```

This will truncate it because of integer division, so make it `10000000.0` to maintain the sub-second portion, or just don't do the division.

It's important to note that the `.Ticks` property you get is relative to Jan 1, 0001 and *not* Jan 1, 1970 like in UNIX which is why you need to subtract that offset above.

**edit**: just for clarity, that nasty constant is just the number of ticks between Jan 1, 0001 and Jan 1, 1970 in UTC.  If you take the seconds portion of it (`62135596800`) and divide by (365 * 24 * 60 * 60) you see you get a number close to `1970`, which is of course not exactly 1970 due to leap adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime.Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) represent units of 100 nanoseconds since Jan. 1, 0001.

Answer (score 0):

On modern CPUs with dynamically varying clock rate, it's very difficult (or expensive) to get accurate sub-millisecond timing.

<strike>I'd suggest that you just multiply the `Milliseconds` property by 1000.</strike>

Use `Ticks` like Jon suggests, but I think your accuracy is still going to be in the neighborhood of 1ms.